# SQL script running endlessly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql script file of size 9.51 MB. When I am running this script on a database its executing successfully within some secs.

But on another large database, it just keep running endlessly.

The first thing I thought that, might be any object is in locked state in that specific database.

I tried running a `[LockCheck.sql]` in a new query window, while the script is still running endlessly. But it did not return any row.

So I believe its not a locking issue, but I can't think of any other reason for this issue.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide more information about sql script file

Comment: is there some code we could look up?

Comment: You need to show the script, otherwise we probably can't help you.

Comment: Can you provide the script? Your question, at the moment, is akin to asking a garage to fix your car, however, not letting them look at said car.

Comment: Please also give some info on the setups. Is that the same server for both databases? How much is the difference in sizes? Is there any difference in structures?

Comment: Try debugging it. My way of debugging is creating a table ( lets say temp)with just 1 column(whatever name).. And write insert query and make entries in the  temp table with values (1),values (2),values (3),values (4), and so on... at various interval in your SQL query. After or during your execution check the temp table. So you will know where is got stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. Its quite a while now. But just wanted to share here how I had solved that. I ran a separate query to find out which code block is causing issues in that large script.

So when that script having issues is still running endlessly, I run the below query pointing to the same database in a separate query window and that helps to locate which section/query is running on server endlessly. It displayed that SQL code in the result-set.

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT as Query_Running_Now,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```